# How can i pass add-on parameters to hosted page API?

Tags: recurly

I want pass add-on parameters(add-on quantity,code etc ) to hosted page API.Like we're passing quantity of plan.
https://:your_subdomain.recurly.com/subscribe/gold?quantity=5

Answer (score 0):

Use some basic steps

1. [Login](http://www.recurly.com) at recurly with your credential.
2. Click on Subscription Plans in left side bar.
3. Select your plan and edit
4. You will find Create Addon Option here.

Comment: Thanks !, but these step i know. i was asking how we can pass add-on parameters to hosted page ?.  Anyway i had contact with support team and got an answer. Thanks again !

Comment: @Yogesh can you elaborate  answer here. it may be more accurate here.